# d3js - force: nodes and links from json file not loaded in my svg during redrawing

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm still trying to load the nodes and links from my extern json file. It works when I do it outside the `redraw()` function. But my goal is to load them and then add additional nodes and link into the `svg`. Thats why I created a `redraw()` function that make the great part of job. I was inspired by this [force example](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043) and this [other example](http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/6c602d7cb14b25c179a4). But nothing appears (I have no error). What do I have to do ?

My code :

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var selected_node = null,
    selected_link = null;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("pointer-events", "all");

var visual = svg
   .append('svg:g')
   .append('svg:g')
      .on("mousemove", mousemove)
      .on("click", click);

visual.append('svg:rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('fill', 'white');

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .on("tick", tick);

// Future link
var drag_line = visual.append("line")
    .attr("class", "drag_line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0);

var nodes = force.nodes(),
    links = force.links();
var node = visual.selectAll(".node"),
    link = visual.selectAll(".link");

// Allows the drag actions 
var drag = force.drag()
  .on("dragstart", dragstart);

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) console.log("error: " + error);   

    nodes = graph.nodes;
    links = graph.links;
});


// Add properties to links and nodes
function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("selected", "selected");
}


function redraw() {
  console.log("redraw start");

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)

  link = link.data(links);

  link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  link.exit().remove();

  node = node.data(nodes);

  node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("fixed", true)
    .call(drag);

  node.exit().transition()
      .attr("r", 0)
      .remove();

  force.start();
}

redraw();
```

Comment: `d3.json(...` is asynchronous so it is possible that you call `redraw();` earlier than the JSON is loaded. Try to place `redraw();` as the last command inside callback `d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) { ... ... redraw();});`

Comment: Thank you very much ! Indeed it works in this way. It's a shame I cannot force to call first a function and then another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user3714582 proposed, the solution is to call `redraw()` (the second function to call) at the end of my first function. If someone has anything to add, he/she's welcome.